# Sabre - airfares and cabins

Tags: sabre

A cabin class (F/J/Y or First/Business/Economy) can have **multiple fare basis** within it, which are designated with specific letters.

For the app I am developing, I need to determine the cabin class of a specific fare basis for a given flight. I am using GetItinerary (*Service action code: TravelItineraryReadRQ*) since I use a PNR, but although it gives the fare basis, I can't seem to find the cabin.
I am pretty sure Sabre has a way of telling, since BargainFinderMax allows you to search through different cabin classes.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the class of service you could check the DU table with VendorCodesLLSRQ to see which cabin it corresponds to for that specific airline.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/utility/get_vendor_codes/

Hope this helps. 
Bruno.

Comment: Here is the new endpoint of this service, the one you gave before is not working anymore: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/utility/get_vendor_codes/ maybe you want to update your answer.